# Issue with RadioButton in AlertDialog

Tags: android, radio-button, android-alertdialog

I have two RadioButtons within a View that is set within an AlertDialog. Although the text for the first one appears horizontal, the text for the second button comes out vertical. Initially, I thought this was due to the View not filling the width of the dialog itself, but that doesn't appear to be the problem (I've tried making the text smaller and the I get the same result). I'm sure I've come across this in the past, but I can't remember how I resolved it. I'm using RadioButtons elsewhere in my app within AlertDialog's with no issue, so I'm pretty stumped. This is what it looks like. At no point do I hard-code the width of any layout or item in dp; I only ever use match_parent or wrap_content:

[image: View as it appears in the AlertDialog]

So, any help in trying to resolve this would be greatly appreciated!

My layout (LayoutInflator is called on it and then values/listeners are applied):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/template"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/check_box"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.45"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="@color/Black" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radio_group"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.55"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:enabled="False">
            <RadioButton 
                    android:id="@+id/radio_button_1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textDirection="ltr"
                    android:enabled="False"
                    android:textColor="@color/Black"/>
             <RadioButton 
                    android:id="@+id/radio_button_2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:enabled="False"
                    android:textColor="@color/Black"
                    android:checked="true"/>
        </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>
```

Inflating the layout like this works fine and gives the desired output:

```
LinearLayout inflatedLayout = (LinearLayout) this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.template, null);
currDialog = CreateDialog.getDialog(this, "Title", inflatedLayout );
currDialog.show();
```

However, when I add this to a TableRow object, which is then added to a TableLayout object, it gives the unexpected result. I'm going to try with a RelativeLayout first.

Comment: Can you show the code of where you show the AlertDialog?

Comment: Yeah, I've just been playing around with that. I have managed to get the RadioButton text to work properly now. If I inflate the view and pass it directly to the AlertDialog, everything works fine. If I try to include the view within a TableLayout as a TableRow, then this problem occurs.

Comment: That makes sense, you never mentioned anything about a TableLayout. I guess that has a width of "wrap_content" instead of "match_parent".

Comment: The TableLayout was hard-coded to match_parent, which is why I've been getting frustrated with this and ended up here. I'm going to switch to a RelativeLayout and see if this problem goes away.

Comment: Problem fixed. The post was a bit of a curve-ball. The issue was with the layout that contained this layout, and my using of the wrong LayoutParams.

Answer (score 0):

You're using layout weights, and you are forcing your RadioGroup take up only 55% of the space. Since the space is not enough, the text goes to vertical. To be 100% sure that your radiogroup will fit, you will need to set it's width to `wrap_content`.

```
<RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radio_group"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:enabled="False">
```

You might also want to consider changing the orientation to `vertical`, in which case it will probably fit with only 55% of the space, but I still highly recommend `wrap_content`

Comment: I use layout weights elsewhere and they work fine. I've tried defining wrap_content for the width parameter, but although the text appears the view is still not filling the dialog screen.

Comment: @confused_at_times Well, in this particular case there's not enough room for both the checkbox and the radiogroup. Sure, layout weights are good when you use them **in the right places**.

Comment: No, I disagree. I have played with the weights so that all the text is aligned horizontally then adjusted it until the 'Disable' text starts to wrap to the next line. This occurs with plenty of space still available on the RHS. I'm guessing there is an issue with the AlertDialog itself and my layout is ok.

Comment: Indeed, if I replace this layout that is inflated with a standard TextView, the entire width of the dialog is filled.

Answer (score 0):

```
android:id="@+id/radio_button_2"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

There isn't enough available space for the second RadioButton to fit it's text, so it stretches the height to be able to fit the text.

Comment: Hi, please see comments above. I don't think this is the problem.

Comment: It is because the RadioGroup has it's width defined by layout_weight, so there's no guarantee it will be able to fit in it's children.

Comment: No, it isn't. The children will fit.

Comment: See previous comments above.

Comment: As Simon has said, using layout_weight in this case will not have the required effect.

Comment: I have it working fine with layout_weight. The issue was the layout it was stored within didn't have the correct LayoutParams set. I fixed this and my layout works correctly with weights. So, this layout was fine all along.